# How to launch web site in chrome headless mode which blocks the headless mode?

Tags: css, python-3.x, selenium, xpath, scrape

Please find below XPATH am using to scrape price from Myntra site. I can able to scrape from all other sites except Myntra and same below XPATH is working in my local windows system with Selenium,Python3 version and using chrome driver.

Driver path : `driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver", options=chrome_options);`

variable_name = `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mountRoot"]/div/div/div/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/p[1]/span/strong').text`

link for reference: https://www.myntra.com/beauty-gift-set/kama-ayurveda/kama-ayurveda-round-the-clock-skincare-gift-set/12800176/buy

When hosted to EC2 ubuntu machine getting below error:
**Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="mountRoot"]/div/div/div/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/p[1]/span/strong"}**

Tried changing XPATH like `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="pdp-price"]//*').text` but no luck.

Comment: It worked well on Mac Catalina. BTW Xpath may break soon. You may use better, shorter and resilient XPaths. Also CSS span.pdp-price>strong is much better.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below XPath

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="pdp-price"]//strong').text
```

Or by Using the below CSS selector

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.pdp-price strong').text
```

The above works only if the site is in GUI mode whereas for headless displays Access Denied attached below screenshot for your reference. Since application blocks headless mode

[image]

Add the below user agent argument and load the web driver to your chrome driver options

```
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox') 
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument(f'user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36')
```

Comment: getting below error: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".pdp-price strong"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=87.0.4280.66)

Comment: weird thing is working in local if we use **CSS** and **XPATH**. Price which am getting : . 1050 (prefixed with dot). Something version issue in EC2 instance?

Comment: @Sharath Site blocks the headless mode try by printing the title in headless mode and GUI mode. In headless mode title is displayed as Access Denied whereas in GUI mode respective title is printed make a try

Comment: @Mohammed is there any way to extract price in Headless mode. Need to automate this on daily basis in EC2 server. Using below arguments for your reference: `chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito") `

Comment: @Sharath Refer to updated answer and make a try.

Comment: @Mohammed, as suggested add above code like `user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.50 Safari/537.36'  `  
`chrome_options.add_argument('user-agent={0}'.format(user_agent))` no luck

Comment: @Sharath Join the chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226657/headless-discussion

Answer (score 0):

Just add this user-agent option while launching headless chrome :
--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36"

```
chromeLauncher.launch({
    chromeFlags: ["--headless", '--disable-gpu', `--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36"`],
    chromePath: '/usr/bin/google-chrome'
})
```